Mouse Cursor Moves Inconsistently on Second Monitor in Linux (Works Fine on Windows)
I keep trying to switch to Linux but am returning to Windows due to an ongoing issue I can't seem to solve. Currently, I’m using Windows, but I genuinely like Linux and would love to make the switch if I can solve this.
I've tried multiple distributions, including Ubuntu, Zorin OS, Mint, and Kali, all with the same problem.
Problem: I’m using a laptop with an additional monitor connected. The second monitor has a larger screen than my laptop display. On Linux, the mouse cursor behaves inconsistently on this larger monitor. While it moves smoothly on the laptop screen, it becomes choppy and moves unevenly on the external monitor—sometimes fast, sometimes slow, making it difficult to click accurately on items. This issue does not occur on Windows; everything works smoothly there.
If anyone has experienced this problem and knows the underlying cause or a fix, I’d appreciate your guidance. I'd love to reinstall Ubuntu if I can resolve this.
I updated the graphics drivers and adjusted the display settings.
